# How to make a custom TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to make a custom text view that has the font set from a given path. Please provide me any example and how I can  make that with less code:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/accountInfoText"
   android:textColor="#727272"
   android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FontTextView extends TextView {


    public FontTextView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica_Neue.ttf"); 
      this.setTypeface(face); 
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
     Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica_Neue.ttf"); 
  this.setTypeface(face); 
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica_Neue.ttf"); 
  this.setTypeface(face); 
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        
       
    }

}
```

and in xml:

```
<com.util.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/accountInfoText"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Comment: I recommend using a singleton for applying the font to avoid creating the typeface from assets each time.

Comment: @JackMahoney +1 for your very helpful comment. Now my application is very fast!!

Comment: @JackMahoney do you have an example of converting a custom view to singleton to show around? Would be helpful.

Comment: @kabuto178 Here is some pseudo-code to give you an idea https://gist.github.com/jackmahoney/9181787

Comment: It's better to use an AppCompatTextView here, you'll even get a warning if you don't use it, the implementation is the exact same, just extend AppCompatTextView instead of TextView.

Comment: According to AndroidX, you can not extend the TextView. You should use AppCompactTextView

Answer (score 49):

Create a Custom View for `Textview`.

1. Make the entry in the `attrs.xml` file and give an option to select Font as a list in custom `TextView`.

   ....
2. Create the enum entry with a list of fonts and assign unique values
3. Make entries of all fonts in `strings.xml`

   Roboto-Bold
   Roboto-Medium
   Roboto-Light
   Roboto-Regular
   Roboto-Thin
   Roboto-Italic
4. Create an asset folder and copy all the necessary font you want to put in the font folder
5. Create a class extending `TextView`

   ```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.res.TypedArray;
   import android.graphics.Typeface;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   /**
   * Created by ANKIT 
   */
   public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {

   String customFont;

   public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       style(context, attrs);
   }

   public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       style(context, attrs);

   }

   private void style(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

       TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
               R.styleable.CustomFontTextView);
       int cf = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_fontName, 0);
       int fontName = 0;
       switch (cf)
       {
           case 1:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Bold;
               break;
           case 2:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Italic;
               break;
           case 3:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Light;
               break;
           case 4:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Medium;
               break;
           case 5:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Regular;
               break;
           case 6:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Thin;
               break;
           default:
               fontName = R.string.Roboto_Regular;
               break;
       }

       customFont = getResources().getString(fontName);

       Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
               "font/" + customFont + ".ttf");
       setTypeface(tf);
       a.recycle();
   }
   }
   ```

You can use this custom class this way. .. use your packageName.ClassName

```
 <ankit.com.customui.CustomFontTextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:text="Hello World Ankit"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  app:fontName="Roboto_Medium"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

add below styleable in res/values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView">
        <attr name="fontName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: much better implementation than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing in Kotlin, this is how you can do it.
First of all, add your font to the **font** folder.
Then, create a separate Kotlin class. Call it something like *HeadlineTextView* (or whatever that sort of gives a hint about what the TextView is for).

```
class HeadlineTextView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView(context, attributeSet) {

  init {
      applyFont()
  }

  private fun applyFont() {
    val headlineTypeface: Typeface=Typeface.create("Montserrat", Typeface.NORMAL)
    typeface=headlineTypeface
  }

}
```

Now use this custom Text View in your XML.
Replace this -

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/accountInfoText"
   android:textColor="#727272"
   android:textSize="18dp" />
```

With this -

```
<com.gmail.something.myapp.HeadlineTextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/accountInfoText"
   android:textColor="#727272"
   android:textSize="18dp" />
```