# Create fashionable textView

Tags: android, textview

I want to create a custom textView which looks like the following blue color sphere/ball :

[image: Example]

The color is to be supplied by the user. Don't know how to create this layout in android xml.
Please help.

Comment: I don't see how this could be TextView, or you are trying to only draw this sphere with another color?

Comment: actually i want to place text inside it. this will be the bg of the textView

Comment: could you provide image of how that textview would look like with text?

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/m4zw82v0h/1352469911_icon_Copy.png

Comment: this will be the background of textview, on which i can place my text elements of different color. Other than this shape, can we create textView of custom shape (say, diamond shape, heart shape.. etc ?)

Comment: I think you can add it as the background and set the textView to be transparent..
or take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview

Answer (score 3):

copy the image (.png format with transparency) to the drawable folder and in the xml set the textview property `android:background="@drawable/your-image-name"`