# How to use new custom class to host a view from layout

Tags: android

When I was working on a new view yesterday I had 7*4 Edit texts , so I had to add lots of code to cover them when the user tries to change the color , for example Red

So I was thinking to do something like this:

```
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_table_colors_Red){

            EditText Holder = (EditText)mView.findViewById(View_ID);
            Holder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.RED);
            return true;
        }
```

The View_ID is from onCreateContextMenu() which tells me which view was clicked on and mView is my fragment view , it works fine and all until I needed to save the values of the colors so the user can return and find the colors that he used:

I found two ways after searching either with a way in 11 api but I need a way to work on 8 api and higher.

the second was to implement a custom Edittext class , I copied the class from the solution to test it and here it is:

```
public class NewEditText extends EditText {
        private int color;
        public NewEditText(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public NewEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public NewEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }   


        @Override
        public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.color=color;
            super.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }

        public int getBackgroundColor() {

            return color;
        }
        }
```

but I'm not sure how to use this ? when I do this it crashes because of " class cast exception "

```
NewEditText holder = (NewEditText)mView.findViewById(View_ID);
```

how am I supposed to use this ? sorry but I've never used a custom class and I couldn't find a solution.

---

Edit 1 the xml , sorry it's kinda big so I decided to post one of the days since there are 7 days and they're the same:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/table_view_mondaylayout"
        android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
        >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Mon"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="125 \n    down"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_monday1"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="125 \n    down"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_monday2"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="125 \n    down"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_monday3"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="125 \n    down"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_monday4"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml you used for mView

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it's so big and mostly the same since it's for the days of the week but I'll post for one day

Comment: I've posted the xml for one day.

Comment: Never thought I should also use the same new custom edittext in the xml I thought since it was it's super class it can just cast it and it'll work, I'll try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview , hopefully it'll work

Comment: yes that was I was looking at right now, of you make a custom view you need to use it in your xml, you cant just cast it direct.