# how to extend TextView with new function

Tags: android, class-design

i have the following code, and the problem, that my function `rlposition()` isn't available from outside the class.

```
public class RLbadge extends TextView {

    public RLbadge(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        this.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.badge);
        this.setTextSize(18);
    }

    public void rlposition(Button pButton) {
        // THIS FUNCTION ISNT SEEN FROM OUTSIDE WHY?
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Why is the function rlposition not visible from outside of the class?
Isn't it possible to add functionality to an extended `TextView`?

Comment: How do you try to access the method? Show us the code please.

Comment: make it static and access it

Answer (score 2):

i now answered the question for myself and put it here maybe somebody needs the answer in the future.

The problem was this line of calling:

```
TextView badgeInfoscan = new RLbadge(this);
badgeInfoscan.rlposition(); // here the error comes
```

changed to

```
RLbadge badgeInfoscan = new RLbadge(this);
badgeInfoscan.rlposition(); // the function is visible
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <YOURPACKAGENAME.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:text="TEASTING" />
```

Here is Class

```
    public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        // Do your staff
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For more details you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview