# How to centralize TextView text with its left drawable vertically

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with a bullet point drawable (which is a circle) on the left like below:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_route"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Route"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/drives_event_route_color"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/blue_bullet"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue_bullet"
    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/lbl_route_size" />
```

Currently, the text and the bullet is aligned on top with each other as shown here:

[image]

Is there a way to vertically centralize the bullet with the text?

Comment: make the actual height of drawable image same as textview height and place the bullet vertically center inside drawable.

Comment: make gravity as center_verticle like this may this help you `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku, I want the bullet image's height to be shorter than the text height

Comment: @Shravankumar: thanks, but It did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Custom TextView
for Reference you can visit : [How to make a custom TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview)

If this is helpfull dont forget to vote.
thanks.