# How to apply font to whole application?

Tags: android

Everyone

I want to apply my custom font to whole application not just a textview or not for an activity. if it is possible make just change in manifest file so it is easy for me.

so help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Is it possible to set font for entire Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)

Comment: [Here's your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16883281/2319542)

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom textview class and use that class whenever you need to use custom fonts.

Check this link: [How to make a custom TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview)

Answer (score 1):

There's also a library that does this. Very simple to use and set up.

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for all activity. Or you can make this method in you utility class and use in you activity class see bellow.

Method in your `utility.java` file.

```
public static void setFont(ViewGroup group, Typeface font) {
    int count = group.getChildCount();
    View v;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        v = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView || v instanceof EditText
                || v instanceof Button) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(font);
        } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
            setFont((ViewGroup) v, font);
    }
}
```

And then in your `Activity.java` file.

```
ll_Homescreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_Homescreen);
FontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), path of you font);
utility.setFont(ll_Homescreen, FontStyle);
```

I hope this will help you Happy Coding.