# custom fonts in android project

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font

im trying to add a custom font in my project, I saw severals tutorials, and in all of them they add the fon programaticly like the following:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/COOPPBL.TTF");
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    tv.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Coukld someone tell me if there a way to add the font in the XML and not using java, thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom fonts and XML layouts (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)

Comment: In android O, there should be way to do that. Until then only java

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-a-custom-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unfortunately cannot. You can do that programmatically only, as android does not have built-in support for that through XML.