# Value of custom TextView is not shown in blueprint

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-custom-view

I wrote a class extending TextView as described here : [How to make a custom TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477393/4698373)

Everything works fine, but I get a very small issue in the blueprint view of the editor :

When you use a regular TextView, its value is shown in the blueprint. Its not the case whith my custom TextView.Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Is there an attribute I have to set in my class to reflect the text value in the blueprint ? Or another solution that I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, actually the problem is that when you make any custom class for layout. It's only being rendered at the time of execution. So it is not able to show text or any properties in preview or blueprint.

Sorry there is no attributes which helps you in rendering this.

Comment: Hi @ankit patidar and thanks for your fast reply ! :) Okay, it was a very small issue, no matter ^^ Have a nice day.