# How can we create custom class of TextView with custom font in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, custom-exceptions

Can anyone help me to define a custom class for android `Textview` with a custom font in `kotlin`?

Comment: you don't need a custom class to use custom font. Normal TextView already supports it.

Comment: If want to add for only Custom Font then it supports already and you don't need to make a new custom class.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can you please give me an example?

Comment: Inspite of this ,If want to make a custom class this link may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-a-custom-textview

Comment: just search for `textview android kotlin font`, should take you around 12 seconds to find answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a folder "**font**" inside "**res**" folder and copy your font

[image]

```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fontFamily="@font/muli_font"
      />
```

**programmatically**

```
 view.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.muli_font))
```

you can download "**.ttf**" font from [here](https://fonts.google.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow following steps to set custom font:-

// Set your font as you want
val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "baamini.ttf")

// Set Your test
txtMessage.text = "Hello world" 

// Set the typeface
txtMessage.typeface = typeface
```