# How to apply letter spacing in custom button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I have one button and letterspacing is not working with it. Please check my following `snippet code`

```
 <style name="ButtonText_v2" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/silka_regular</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dimen_14dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PrimaryButton_v2" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_selector_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="textAppearance">@style/ButtonText_v2</item>
    </style>
```

### layout.xml File

```
<Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            style="@style/PrimaryButton_v2"

            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  `android:letterSpacing` in `PrimaryButton_v2` it will work perfectly.

```
        <style name="ButtonText_v2" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
            <item name="fontFamily">@font/silka_regular</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dimen_14dp</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="PrimaryButton_v2" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_selector_primary</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
            <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
            <item name="textAppearance">@style/ButtonText_v2</item>
            <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.1</item>
        </style>
```

**layout.xml File**

```
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        style="@style/PrimaryButton_v2"

        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        />
```

Comment: if it worked don't forget to accept the answer so that other's can also take benefit from your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply letter spacing in button/custom button because their is some limitation in button component in which you can't make text appearance and background customization and more limitation
the solution for this is instead of button you can use text view and make custom text view it will also work similar to button and customize it according to requirement.
for example :-
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-a-custom-textview#:~:text=Create%20a%20Custom%20View%20for%20Textview.%20Make%20the,values%20Make%20entries%20of%20all%20fonts%20in%20strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-a-custom-textview#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20Custom%20View%20for%20Textview.%20Make%20the,values%20Make%20entries%20of%20all%20fonts%20in%20strings.xml)